# Are unittest attributes mutable in Python?

Tags: python, unit-testing

Suppose I have this integration test

```
class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.key = '123'

    def test_01_create_acc(self):
       user = create_account(...)
       self.key = user.key

    def test_02_check_account(self):
       user = check_account(..)
       self.assertEqual(self.key, user.key)
```

It looks like the attribute `self.key` is not mutable. It stays with the old value from `setUpClass`. But isn't `setUpClass` only called once?

The account function creates a key randomly for security reason, so I am not allowed to pass in my secret key. It returns the key, so I need to modify that attribute. Can I?

It looks like each `test_` case is isolated.

```
my_gloabl = None

def setUpClass(cls):
    cls.key = my_global
```

If I change `my_global` in test1, test2 will get `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class is set up only once. But each test method is actually called from a different instance of that test.

You can demonstrate this using the `id` function, which will return a different number for each object:

```
import unittest

class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        print "setup"

    def test_01_create_acc(self):
        print id(self)

    def test_02_check_account(self):
        print id(self)

unittest.main()
```

On my computer, this printed:

```
setup
4300479824
.4300479888
```

Note how the `setup` method was called only once, *but* the id of the instance for test1 and test2 are different.

Comment: Thanks. So you are saying each test is indeed isolated. If `self` is different, doesn't it mean this is a `fork`?

Comment: No, `fork` does not anything to do with this. It's just that when you build a suite(or when unittest builds it) it does something like `suite=Suite(MyTestCase('test_name'), MyTestCase('test_name2'),...)` thus it creates more instances of the class.

Avoid dependencies between tests. They are usually unneeded and make everything harder.

Comment: Exactly- multiple instances of the same class (all in the same process, not anything like a fork). Also note that there is no guarantee what order tests will run it, another reason to avoid dependencies between them.